# import error dll load failed a dynamic link library (dll) initialization routine failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, ipython

```
DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.


c\:>python
>>>import tensorflow as tf
```

Then I get
    File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
    packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 24, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
    File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
    packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 49, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
    File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
    packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
    raise ImportError(msg)
    ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
    packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
    File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
    packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
    File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
    packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
    File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in 
    load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in 
    load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
    ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

```
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

Comment: What is your question? Also, that error message is very difficult to read. If you're having trouble with the formatting, include it as basic text and someone else can add the formatting later.

Comment: I got those errors when I import tensorflow, can you help me to find the solution ?

Comment: We're going to need more information on your environment.

Comment: OS => Windows 8.1 CPU => Pentium and No GPU

Comment: What packages do you have installed which could be interfering here? How did you install TensorFlow?